# High-order antiderivatives of the Weierstrass P-function

Tags: integration, closed-form, elliptic-functions

The Weierstrass P-function, $\wp(z;g_2,g_3)$ and its derivative $\wp'(z;g_2,g_3)$ are the building blocks of all elliptic functions of a given period lattice. The differential equation 
$$\wp''=6\wp^2-\frac{1}{2} g_2 $$
implies that all derivatives $\wp^{(n)}$ can be expressed as polynomials in $\wp,\wp'$. Recently, I've tried exploring antiderivatives.

The Mathematica command

```
Integrate[WeierstrassP[z,{g2,g3}],z]
```

shows that
$$\int \wp(z;g_2,g_3) \mathrm{d} z=-\zeta(z;g_2,g_3)+A $$
where $A$ is an arbitrary constant, and $\zeta$ is the [Weierstrass Zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassZetaFunction.html). Moreover, the command

```
Integrate[WeierstrassP[z,{g2,g3}],z,z]
```

shows that

$$\int - \zeta(z; g_2,g_3) \mathrm{d} z=- \log \sigma(z;g_2,g_3)+B $$
where $B$ is an arbitrary constant, and $\sigma$ is the [Weierstrass Sigma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassSigmaFunction.html). Trying a third time, the command

```
 Integrate[WeierstrassP[z,{g2,g3}],z,z,z]
```

returns the unevaluated integral
$$-\int \log \sigma(z;g_2,g_3) \mathrm{d} z. $$

My questions are: is it really not possible to express $\wp^{(-n)}$ in terms of other known functions for $n \geq 3$? Are there any other known expressions for $\wp^{(-n)}$ with $n \geq 3$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There could be...the integral$$\int x^2\wp(x+z)\,dx\tag1$$has two periods as a function of $z$, and using IBP twice, will produce$$-x^2\zeta(x+z)+2x\ln\sigma(x+z)-2\int \ln\sigma(x+z)\,dx$$

But the integrand in $(1)$ has second-order poles; thus its integral can be evaluated as a series of residues, implying it can be rewritten as a sum of Weierstrass zeta functions (in $z$). Finally, set $z=0$.

Higher-order antiderivatives can be handled similarly by increasing the exponent in $(1)$.

Comment: The second anti-derivative of $\wp_(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{n,m}' \frac{1}{(z-n\tau-m)^2}-\frac{1}{(n\tau+m)^2}$ is $A+Cz-\log(z)-\sum_{n,m} (\log(1+\frac{z}{n\tau-m})-\frac{z}{n\tau-m}+\frac{z^2}{2(n\tau-m)^2})$

Comment: What happens when you add $1$ or $\tau$ to $z$? I think the sum can be regularized...I'll look into it soon. Try treating it formally!

Comment: What do you mean ? I have regularized the sums to make them absolutely convergent

Comment: Oh, OK. The summand can be rewritten as $\sum_{k\ge3}\tfrac{(-1)^{k-1}z^k}{k(n\tau-m)^k}$, but I don't know if that makes the series any easier to evaluate.

Comment: And this is the logarithm of Weierstrass [$\sigma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_functions#Weierstrass_zeta_function) function, which is how he obtained doubly periodic functions and his Weierstrass product for arbitrary entire functions

Comment: So the second antiderivative of $\wp$ contains $\ln\sigma$ (along with elementary functions)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69194/discussion-between-antonio-djc-and-reuns).