# Higher derivatives $\wp^{(2n)}$ of the Weierstrass $\wp$-function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

I'm interested in considering the Weierstrass $\wp$-function denoted $\wp(\tau, z)$ as well as its higher derivatives $\wp^{(2n)}$, for all $n \geq 0$.  The derivatives are with respect to the $z$ variable, and I refer to this highly related question ([Calculating derivatives of the Weierstrass $\wp$-function in terms of $\wp$ and $\wp '$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2644640/calculating-derivatives-of-the-weierstrass-wp-function-in-terms-of-wp-and)) for definitions and such.

In an answer to the above referenced question, a user points out that using the relation

$$(\wp^{(1)})^{2} = 4\wp^{3} - \wp g_{2} - g_{3},$$

one can easily produce the following result

$$\wp^{(2)} = 6 \wp^{2} - \frac{1}{2}g_{2},$$

and one could then show that all higher derivatives are a polynomial in $\wp, \wp^{(1)}, g_{2}$, and $g_{3}$.  It's easy to convince oneself that for even derivatives $\wp^{(2n)}$ there is no dependence on $\wp^{(1)}$, so we should be able to write it as a polynomial in $\wp, g_{2}$, and $g_{3}$.

My question is: do we have a general formula for this polynomial for all $n \geq 0$?  I tried coming up with it myself and it seems to quickly become unbearable.  If there isn't a closed form, is there anything theoretically notable (aside from the obvious) about the polynomial?  Is there anything we can really say about it?  I feel like this must exist somewhere out there, and I'm just unable to find it.